# Distinct works on IQueryable but not List<T>?? Why?

Tags: linq, distinct

[image]

First Table is the View and Second is the result I want

This below query works fine

```
List<BTWStudents> students = (from V in db.vwStudentCoursesSD
        where classIds.Contains(V.Class.Value)
        select new BTWStudents
                    {
                    StudentId = V.StudentId
                    Amount= V.PaymentMethod == "Cashier Check" ? V.Amount: "0.00"
                    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

But I changed it to List to add string formatting(see below)

```
List<BTWStudents> students = (from V in db.vwStudentCoursesSD
        where classIds.Contains(V.Class.Value)
        select new {V}).ToList().Select(x => new BTWStudents
                    {
                    StudentId = V.StudentId
                    Amount= V.PaymentMethod == "Cashier Check" ? String.Format("{0:c}",V.Amount): "0.00"
                    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

With this Second Query I get this

[image]

Why is distinct not working in the second query?

Comment: Did you deliberately remove the `V.PaymentMethod == "Cashier Check" ?` section in your second example?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo.. it was ok in my code

Comment: There are so many "typos" in that example, it doesn't even compile. Have you implemented the `IEquatable<BTWStudents>` interface on your object? Do you have an equality comparer implemented? `Distinct()` depends on those implementations.

Comment: no I haven't.. I am going to look into it. Sorry about the typos. I am just trying to understand how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with objects (in your case a wrapped anonymous type because you are using Select new {V} rather than just Select V), Distinct calls the object.Equals when doing the comparison. Internally, this checks the object's hash code. You'll find in this case, the hash code of the two objects is different even though the fields contain the same values. To fix this, you will need to override Equals on the object type or pass a custom IEqualityComparer implementation into the Distinct overload. You should be able to find a number of examples online searching for "Distinct IEqualityComparer".

Answer (score 0):

Try this (moved your distinct to the first query and corrected your bugged if/then/else):

```
List<BTWStudents> students = (from V in db.vwStudentCoursesSD
    where classIds.Contains(V.Class.Value)
    select new {V}).Distinct().ToList().Select(x => new BTWStudents
                {
                classId = V.Class.HasValue ? V.Class.Value : 0,
                studentName = V.StudentName,          
                paymentAmount = V.PaymentMethod == "Cashier Check" ? String.Format("{0:c}",x.V.AmountOwed): "0.00"
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Adding Distinct here wont give unique values because AmountOwed Column in the View has different values for same Student, that's why I made it equal 0 in List and then I was doing a distinct

Comment: That doesn't make sense. AmountOwed is one of the columns in your resulting BTWStudents object you are trying to get a distinct list of.

Comment: AmountOwed has different values for same student when PaymentMethod is not CashierCheck thats why I do this

paymentAmount = V.PaymentMethod == "Cashier Check" ? V.AmountOwed:"0.00"

I am displaying payment amount = 0 when Payment Method is not cashier's check

Answer (score 0):

You can get around using `Distinct` all together if you `Group` by StudentID

```
var studentsGroupedByPayment =
    (from V in db.vwStudentCoursesSD
    where classIds.Contains(V.Class.Value)
    group V by V.StudentId into groupedV
    select new
    {
        StudentID = groupedV.Key,
        Amount = string.Format("{0:C}",
                      groupedV.First().PaymentMethod == "Cashier Check" ?
                      groupedV.First().Amount : 0.0)
    }
    ).ToList();
```